# Generic PHPDoc with IntelliJ / PhpStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, annotations, phpstorm

I was watching the founder of phps talk here:

https://youtu.be/rKXFgWP-2xQ?t=27m26s

notice at 27m 26s

[image]

Is this supported by IntelliJ IDEA / PhpStorm or not? My version does not seem to know it.

Is there maybe a plugin?

Am I missing something? I thought I'm up to date with PHPDocs

Comment: AFAIK it's not yet supported by PhpStorm -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31960. It was in [PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) which was abandoned (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)... so I do not know how other tools/IDEs support such syntax.

Comment: FYI, that's the generic arrays syntax supported by the package mentioned in the video ([phan](https://github.com/phan/phan)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be supported by PHPStorm in a future release. It's currently supported in EAP build 183.2635.12 and looks like it will be a part of the 2018.3 release.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/09/phpstorm-2018-3-eap-183-2635-12/

Comment: It has been removed from the PSR-5, any idea what happened to the PhpStorm implementation? It doesn't seem to work as expected.